# Logic app job run status through api call

Tags: azure

I am trying to configure logic app job which involves calling multiple services in sequence. We have to test the flow as part of our testing by calling logic app url and monitor whether job is getting completed successfully and validate whether all the services invoked behaved as expected.

Is there any way to track the status of the logic app run through any api calls? So that I could check status of job and then start validations rather than validate it post fixed time?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Azure's Management API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowruns/get

The APIs give you all runs that are available in your Logic Apps (based on your retention time) and gives you an overall status, but also provides you with the status of the trigger and all actions. Giving you the possibility to really dive depper into what happens within your logic app for each and every run.

To enable or use this, you can follow this article to learn more on how to use the management API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code.
It requires you to register an application in your AD.

**A side node**:

At [Nodinite](https://nodinite.com) we provide a platform that does such monitoring. For each Logic App you have you in your subscriptions, we are not just evaluating if the Logic Apps are enabled, we also provide a way to monitor the status of all runs.

[image: Azure Logic Apps Monitor]

We also provide a way to get more information on the runs that have failed - or even start and stop your Logic Apps. However we also provide logging of Logic Apps for you to get more details on all kind of runs, even those which succeeded. You can read more on this here on our documentation page for Azure Logic Apps Logging & Monitoring: https://documentation.nodinite.com/Documentation/LoggingAndMonitoring/Azure%20Logic%20Apps?doc=/Overview

Comment: Hello @robert-m, this is a helpful answer.  How do you get the run name from the original request in order to request the status of the job?  When I send a request I just get a response 202 back from azure.